# How to crop the image using LaTeX?

Tags: latex

For example I have a image with some description. I want to crop the image such that only image is visible. How I can do in LaTeX ?

Comment: Hi and welcome here!! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

`graphicx` provides a trim option which allows you to specify how much should be trimmed on the left, bottom, right and top:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[trim= 0 0 90 0,clip]{example-image-duck}

\end{document}
```